# Can't getting some tags by using soup.findAll?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

This is an HTML code, as you can see there are two tags i.e. `<code>, <img>`.
Now what on I want your focus on is that, when you scroll a **little** right you will see a `code` tag right after `img` tag.

## Problem

Now the main problem is, I want all code tags, I am using bs4 for that, but **I can get the code tags which are right after the image tags.** I don't know why?. Any idea?

```
<code style="display: none" id="bpr-guid-1535430">
      {&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;mediaConfig&quot;:{&quot;mprConfig&quot;:{&quot;sizes&quot;:[{&quot;width&quot;:60,&quot;height&quot;:30,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:60,&quot;height&quot;:36,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:90,&quot;height&quot;:45,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:90,&quot;height&quot;:54,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:100,&quot;height&quot;:50,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:100,&quot;height&quot;:60,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:100,&quot;height&quot;:100,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:120,&quot;height&quot;:60,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:120,&quot;height&quot;:72,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:127,&quot;height&quot;:30,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:127,&quot;height&quot;:46,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:150,&quot;height&quot;:75,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:150,&quot;height&quot;:90,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:191,&quot;height&quot;:45,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:191,&quot;height&quot;:69,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:200,&quot;height&quot;:100,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:200,&quot;height&quot;:120,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:200,&quot;height&quot;:200,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:254,&quot;height&quot;:60,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:254,&quot;height&quot;:92,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:337,&quot;height&quot;:120,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:400,&quot;height&quot;:400,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:506,&quot;height&quot;:180,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:674,&quot;height&quot;:240,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;},{&quot;width&quot;:750,&quot;height&quot;:750,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorSize&quot;}],&quot;filters&quot;:{&quot;cover&quot;:&quot;https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_{width}_{height}{+id}&quot;,&quot;contain&quot;:&quot;https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_{width}_{height}{+id}&quot;,&quot;original&quot;:&quot;https://media.licdn.com/media{+id}&quot;,&quot;fill&quot;:&quot;https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_{width}_{height}{+id}&quot;,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorFilters&quot;},&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaProcessorConfig&quot;},&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.MediaConfig&quot;},&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.Configuration&quot;},&quot;included&quot;:[]}
    </code>

<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" style="display: none" class="datalet-bpr-guid-1535430"><code style="display: none" id="bpr-guid-1535431">
  {&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;canBrowseProfiles&quot;:false,&quot;reactivationFeaturesEligible&quot;:false,&quot;canViewJobAnalytics&quot;:false,&quot;canViewWVMP&quot;:false,&quot;premiumFreeTrialEligible&quot;:true,&quot;canViewCompanyInsights&quot;:false,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.premium.FeatureAccess&quot;},&quot;included&quot;:[]}
</code>

<code style="display: none" id="datalet-bpr-guid-1535431">
  {"request":"/voyager/api/premium/featureAccess?name\u003DreactivationFeaturesEligible","status":200,"body":"bpr-guid-1535431"}
</code>

<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" style="display: none" class="datalet-bpr-guid-1535431"><code style="display: none" id="bpr-guid-1535432">
  {&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;companies&quot;:[],&quot;$deletedFields&quot;:[&quot;paidProducts&quot;,&quot;postJobsEnabled&quot;],&quot;memberGroup&quot;:&quot;FREE&quot;,&quot;showStaticLearning&quot;:false,&quot;$type&quot;:&quot;com.linkedin.voyager.common.Nav&quot;,&quot;$id&quot;:&quot;M8x5UY0Zt6eGdBCiy+iKhA&#61;&#61;,root&quot;},&quot;included&quot;:[]}
</code>

<code style="display: none" id="datalet-bpr-guid-1535432">
  {"request":"/voyager/api/nav","status":200,"body":"bpr-guid-1535432"}
</code>
```

Below is the code I am using in python.

```
h = HTMLParser()

companyname = sys.argv[1]

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0',
   
}
url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords='+companyname+'&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER'
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
finding = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')



for x in finding.findAll('code'):
    print x
```

Comment: you're not getting the other tags because your just pulling <code> tags. if you want the <img> tags, you'll need to do `finding.findAll('img')`

Comment: Try `finding.select('img ~ code')`, it will select all `code` tags that are the next sibling of `img` tags.

Comment: @t.m.adam Thanks for the suggestion but you are forgetting that I want not only the code tags which are right after the image tag but also other code tags So please provide the solution by looking at this point.

Comment: becuase now I have to use two different codes to extracting code tags which I don't want. Thanks, looking for your reply.

Comment: Hi I tried but I only get one code tag, is there any other attributes like `selectall` `selectAll`.

Comment: `.select()` returns a list of tags (like `.find_all()`), `.select_one()` returns only the first tag (like `.find()`). The css-selector in my previous comment selects all `code` tags that are after a `img` tag, if you want all `code` tags use `.select('code')` or just use your current code. Note that the html you get with `requests` may be different than what you see in your browser, because of js generated content. In that case you can use a client that runs js, like `Selenium` for example.